# How Do I Refactor Terraform Code To Modules?

Tags: terraform

I started off with 3 separate terraform directories for networking, vms and databases (in Azure) and I would do `terraform apply` in each of these.

There is some duplication in the terraform files such as the Azure resource group in each file.

```
# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource-group" {
  name     = "terraform-rg"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

Therefore, I now want to restructure the code so all 3 are called from a single `main.tf` at the root and I only do `terraform apply` once.

However, I am new to this and I'm not sure how to reference the resource group if it is in the root directory and no longer in the same file.

E.g. the vnet used for the VM looks like this:

```
# Create a virtual network for the VM
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm-vnet" {
  name                = "terraform-client1-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name   
}
```

The `location` and `resource_group_name` no longer resolve because `azurerm_resource_group.resource-group` is no longer in the same file but in the `main.tf` at the root.

What is the process for refactoring this correctly so that everything resolves?

Is there an `import` statement?

Answer (score 1):

The modules work as below way.

Suppose you have below folders

```
modules
  - resource-group
  - networking
  - vms
  - databases
```

make sure you set the proper output in  module `resource-group` as below way

> Notes, in terraform version v0.12+, maybe you needn't set output variables any more, it should work directly, but I didn't have chance to test

Under folder `modules/resource-group`, you can prepare this file `main.tf`

```
# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource-group" {
  name     = "terraform-rg"
  location = "eastus"
}

output "resource-group-location" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.location
}

output "resource-group-name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
}
```

Now you can easily reference the resource in another modules

```
module "resource-group"{
  source = "../resource-group"
  ...
}

# Create a virtual network for the VM
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm-vnet" {
  name                = "terraform-client1-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = module.resource-group.resource-group-location
  resource_group_name = module.resource-group.resource-group-name   
}
```